# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on mysql result

Tags: php, mysql

The below code give me a foreach error.  What appears to be the issue with my code?

```
 $my_word = $_REQUEST['value'];
$bestMatch = array('word' => $my_word, 'match' => 2);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT keyword FROM keywords");
$storeArray = Array();
foreach ($result as $keyword) {
    $lev = levenshtein ($keyword, $my_word, 1, 2, 1);
    if (!isset($lowest) || $lev < $lowest) {
       $bestMatch = array('word' => $keyword, 'match' => $lev);
       $lowest = $lev;
    }
}
if ($bestMatch['match'] > 0)
   echo 'Did you mean: <strong>'.$bestMatch['word'].'</strong> l:'.$bestMatch['match'];
```

Comment: And the foreach error is....?

Comment: the error would also be useful...

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use mysql_* anymore, but PDO or mysqli.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: @Jeroen yeah im currently learning PDO so it better right now to use Mysql

Comment: How can I improve this question (which is 7 years old) to get better reception from the community?  This question got me banned today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
foreach ($result as $keyword)
```

With this:

```
while ($keyword = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

[mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) just returns a resource, you need the actual results, so you need to use [mysql_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) as well.

Also, the mysql_* functions are being deprecated so you should look into PDO or mysqli.

Comment: I saw that just wanted to make sure you noticed it :)

Comment: In that case, you should have just said "It should be while(), but thanks!"; I already know how this works, just forgot to change it.

Comment: @Jeroen sorry man.. thank you for the answer though.. its working now

Answer (score 0):

The foreach requires an array. You look to be passing the query instead, have a look at [mysql-fetch-array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) to get an array of results from your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT keyword FROM keywords");
```

This returns a resource that you need to process with other functions. For instance:
http://us.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc

Check http://us.php.net/mysql_query

On another note, MySQL might have some functions like levenshtein that you can use.